# Validation Accuracy is higher than training accuracy using Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use deep learning to predict DNA sequences. First, I converted my data word to vectors.

We're getting rather odd results, where our validation data is getting better accuracy and lower loss, than our training data. And this is consistent across different sizes of hidden layers. This is our model:

Here is the entire code:

```
        import numpy as np
        import tensorflow as tf
        
        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv1D
        from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling1D
        import os
        import sys
        from keras.utils import to_categorical
        from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, precision_recall_fscore_support, accuracy_score
        
        from keras.models import Sequential
        from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Dropout
        from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
        from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adam, Adadelta
        from keras.utils import np_utils
        from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, AveragePooling1D
        from keras.layers import Bidirectional
        from keras.models import load_model
        from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
        from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
        from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
        from keras.layers import Reshape
        from keras.constraints import maxnorm
        from keras.callbacks import Callback
        from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
        from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
        from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
        from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
        import os
        import random
        from keras.layers import LSTM
    
    Xfeat = []; Ylab = []
    
    for line in open('/home/vinoth/SKKU/CBB-Projects/project12/iPro-WAEL-main/feature/NHEK/train/final2-kmer5-without-strings.txt'):
        v = line.split()
        ndata = list(map(float,v[1:-1]))
        Xfeat.append(ndata)
        Ylab.append([float(v[-1])])
    Xfeat=np.array(Xfeat); Ylab = np.array(Ylab)
    
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xfeat, Ylab, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)
    
    x_train
    x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,1000,1)
    x_test =  x_test.reshape(-1,1000,1)
    #y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1,1)
    y_test = y_test.reshape(-1,1,1)
    
    x_train.shape
    (688, 1000, 1)
    y_train.shape
    (688, 1)
    y_test.shape
    (173, 1, 1)
    x_test.shape
    (173, 1000, 1)
    
    KERNEL_SIZE = 11
    KERNEL_NUM = 32
    
    def cnn():
        #set_seed(10)
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv1D(KERNEL_NUM, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(1000,1), name='conv_1'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D())
    
        model.add(Conv1D(KERNEL_NUM, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv_2'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D())
    
        model.add(Conv1D(KERNEL_NUM, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv_3'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D())
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(1e-4), name='Dense_1'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', activity_regularizer = regularizers.l1(1e-4), name='Dense_2'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        
        return model
    model = cnn()
    model.summary()
    
    Model: "sequential_34"
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    conv_1 (Conv1D)              (None, 1000, 32)          384       
    _________________________________________________________________
    max_pooling1d_94 (MaxPooling (None, 500, 32)           0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv_2 (Conv1D)              (None, 500, 32)           11296     
    _________________________________________________________________
    max_pooling1d_95 (MaxPooling (None, 250, 32)           0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv_3 (Conv1D)              (None, 250, 32)           11296     
    _________________________________________________________________
    max_pooling1d_96 (MaxPooling (None, 125, 32)           0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout_70 (Dropout)         (None, 125, 32)           0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    flatten_32 (Flatten)         (None, 4000)              0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    Dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                256064    
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout_71 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    Dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout_72 (Dropout)         (None, 1)                 0         
    =================================================================
    Total params: 279,105
    Trainable params: 279,105
    Non-trainable params: 0
    _________________________________________________________________

#set early stopping criteria
pat = 5 #this is the number of epochs with no improvment after which the training will stop
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=pat, verbose=1)

#define the model checkpoint callback -> this will keep on saving the model as a physical file
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('fas_mnist_1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
LOSS = 'binary_crossentropy'
learning_rate = 0.001

def fit_and_evaluate(x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val, EPOCHS=3, BATCH_SIZE=128):
    model = None
    model = cnn()
    model.compile(loss=LOSS, optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
    results = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint], 
              verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)  
    print("Val Score: ", model.evaluate(x_val, y_val))
    return results

n_folds=5
epochs=15
batch_size=32

#save the model history in a list after fitting so that we can plot later
model_history = [] 

for i in range(n_folds):
    print("Training on Fold: ",i+1)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, 
                                               random_state = np.random.randint(1,1000, 1)[0])
    model_history.append(fit_and_evaluate(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, epochs, batch_size))
    print("======="*12, end="\n\n\n")



Training on Fold:  1
Train on 557 samples, validate on 62 samples
Epoch 1/15
557/557 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8426 - accuracy: 0.7828 - val_loss: 0.2406 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.24061, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 2/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 667us/step - loss: 1.1648 - accuracy: 0.9282 - val_loss: 0.1430 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.24061 to 0.14302, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 3/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 622us/step - loss: 1.2546 - accuracy: 0.9228 - val_loss: 0.1075 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.14302 to 0.10746, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 4/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 625us/step - loss: 1.4153 - accuracy: 0.9120 - val_loss: 0.1039 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 0.10746 to 0.10390, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 5/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 629us/step - loss: 1.3033 - accuracy: 0.9192 - val_loss: 0.0983 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.10390 to 0.09832, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 6/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 628us/step - loss: 1.4978 - accuracy: 0.9066 - val_loss: 0.1200 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.09832
Epoch 7/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 628us/step - loss: 1.1344 - accuracy: 0.9300 - val_loss: 0.1005 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.09832
Epoch 8/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 609us/step - loss: 1.5216 - accuracy: 0.9048 - val_loss: 0.0947 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00008: val_loss improved from 0.09832 to 0.09471, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 9/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 645us/step - loss: 1.2982 - accuracy: 0.9192 - val_loss: 0.0961 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 0.09471
Epoch 10/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 637us/step - loss: 1.5451 - accuracy: 0.9031 - val_loss: 0.0984 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.09471
Epoch 11/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 620us/step - loss: 1.4087 - accuracy: 0.9120 - val_loss: 0.1009 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 0.09471
Epoch 12/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 621us/step - loss: 1.3490 - accuracy: 0.9156 - val_loss: 0.0911 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00012: val_loss improved from 0.09471 to 0.09107, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 13/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 652us/step - loss: 1.4596 - accuracy: 0.9084 - val_loss: 0.0866 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00013: val_loss improved from 0.09107 to 0.08656, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 14/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 680us/step - loss: 1.3203 - accuracy: 0.9174 - val_loss: 0.0919 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 0.08656
Epoch 15/15
557/557 [==============================] - 0s 607us/step - loss: 1.3484 - accuracy: 0.9156 - val_loss: 0.0846 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00015: val_loss improved from 0.08656 to 0.08460, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
69/69 [==============================] - 0s 287us/step
Val Score:  [0.0857580542780351, 1.0]
====================================================================================


Training on Fold:  2
Train on 501 samples, validate on 56 samples
Epoch 1/15
501/501 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 2.0226 - accuracy: 0.7665 - val_loss: 0.2116 - val_accuracy: 0.8571

Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 2/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 634us/step - loss: 1.7075 - accuracy: 0.8962 - val_loss: 0.1173 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 3/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 656us/step - loss: 1.3325 - accuracy: 0.9182 - val_loss: 0.1080 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 4/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 615us/step - loss: 1.6302 - accuracy: 0.8982 - val_loss: 0.0883 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 5/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 645us/step - loss: 1.7822 - accuracy: 0.8882 - val_loss: 0.0891 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 6/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 632us/step - loss: 1.5645 - accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 0.0889 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 7/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 646us/step - loss: 1.4683 - accuracy: 0.9082 - val_loss: 0.0875 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.08460
Epoch 8/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 647us/step - loss: 1.4081 - accuracy: 0.9122 - val_loss: 0.0842 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00008: val_loss improved from 0.08460 to 0.08422, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 9/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 662us/step - loss: 1.5606 - accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 0.0834 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 0.08422 to 0.08338, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 10/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 657us/step - loss: 1.8972 - accuracy: 0.8802 - val_loss: 0.0821 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00010: val_loss improved from 0.08338 to 0.08214, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 11/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 679us/step - loss: 1.3781 - accuracy: 0.9142 - val_loss: 0.0810 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00011: val_loss improved from 0.08214 to 0.08100, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 12/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 667us/step - loss: 1.6815 - accuracy: 0.8942 - val_loss: 0.0789 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00012: val_loss improved from 0.08100 to 0.07887, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 13/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 636us/step - loss: 1.4630 - accuracy: 0.9082 - val_loss: 0.0792 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00013: val_loss did not improve from 0.07887
Epoch 14/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 631us/step - loss: 1.6462 - accuracy: 0.8962 - val_loss: 0.0776 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00014: val_loss improved from 0.07887 to 0.07760, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 15/15
501/501 [==============================] - 0s 661us/step - loss: 1.5238 - accuracy: 0.9042 - val_loss: 0.0808 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
62/62 [==============================] - 0s 185us/step
Val Score:  [0.1335997413243017, 1.0]
====================================================================================


Training on Fold:  3
Train on 450 samples, validate on 51 samples
Epoch 1/15
450/450 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.9834 - accuracy: 0.7044 - val_loss: 0.2369 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 2/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 639us/step - loss: 1.5691 - accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 0.1211 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 3/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 627us/step - loss: 1.2025 - accuracy: 0.9267 - val_loss: 0.0999 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 4/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 645us/step - loss: 1.5382 - accuracy: 0.9044 - val_loss: 0.0999 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 5/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 629us/step - loss: 1.7783 - accuracy: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.1005 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 6/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 639us/step - loss: 1.4978 - accuracy: 0.9067 - val_loss: 0.1061 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 7/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 623us/step - loss: 1.2553 - accuracy: 0.9222 - val_loss: 0.0825 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 8/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 631us/step - loss: 1.2917 - accuracy: 0.9200 - val_loss: 0.0905 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 9/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 620us/step - loss: 1.1206 - accuracy: 0.9311 - val_loss: 0.1114 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 10/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 646us/step - loss: 1.5620 - accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 0.0962 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 11/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 626us/step - loss: 1.5598 - accuracy: 0.9022 - val_loss: 0.1174 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 12/15
450/450 [==============================] - 0s 624us/step - loss: 1.5231 - accuracy: 0.9044 - val_loss: 0.0991 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00012: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 00012: early stopping
56/56 [==============================] - 0s 181us/step
Val Score:  [0.08678687257426125, 1.0]
====================================================================================


Training on Fold:  4
Train on 405 samples, validate on 45 samples
Epoch 1/15
405/405 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6832 - accuracy: 0.7259 - val_loss: 0.3220 - val_accuracy: 0.7778

Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 2/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 676us/step - loss: 1.7706 - accuracy: 0.8938 - val_loss: 0.1151 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 3/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 675us/step - loss: 1.5160 - accuracy: 0.9062 - val_loss: 0.1018 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 4/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 632us/step - loss: 1.4722 - accuracy: 0.9086 - val_loss: 0.0936 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 5/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 647us/step - loss: 1.5054 - accuracy: 0.9062 - val_loss: 0.1020 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 6/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 631us/step - loss: 1.4272 - accuracy: 0.9111 - val_loss: 0.0786 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 7/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 629us/step - loss: 1.3882 - accuracy: 0.9136 - val_loss: 0.0957 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 8/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 659us/step - loss: 1.3118 - accuracy: 0.9185 - val_loss: 0.0867 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 9/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 626us/step - loss: 1.2345 - accuracy: 0.9235 - val_loss: 0.0870 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 10/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 628us/step - loss: 1.2305 - accuracy: 0.9235 - val_loss: 0.0915 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 11/15
405/405 [==============================] - 0s 634us/step - loss: 1.1159 - accuracy: 0.9309 - val_loss: 0.0790 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 00011: early stopping
51/51 [==============================] - 0s 204us/step
Val Score:  [0.10347107914732952, 1.0]
====================================================================================


Training on Fold:  5
Train on 364 samples, validate on 41 samples
Epoch 1/15
364/364 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.9625 - accuracy: 0.6731 - val_loss: 0.4000 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00001: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 2/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 687us/step - loss: 1.4853 - accuracy: 0.9121 - val_loss: 0.1366 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 3/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 660us/step - loss: 1.7694 - accuracy: 0.8901 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 4/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 656us/step - loss: 1.3373 - accuracy: 0.9176 - val_loss: 0.1144 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 5/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 668us/step - loss: 1.6727 - accuracy: 0.8956 - val_loss: 0.0925 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 6/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 649us/step - loss: 1.8405 - accuracy: 0.8846 - val_loss: 0.0863 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 7/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 635us/step - loss: 1.1173 - accuracy: 0.9313 - val_loss: 0.0985 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 8/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 646us/step - loss: 1.6682 - accuracy: 0.8956 - val_loss: 0.1020 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 0.07760
Epoch 9/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 650us/step - loss: 1.1203 - accuracy: 0.9313 - val_loss: 0.0761 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 0.07760 to 0.07611, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 10/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 659us/step - loss: 1.3695 - accuracy: 0.9148 - val_loss: 0.0745 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00010: val_loss improved from 0.07611 to 0.07454, saving model to fas_mnist_1.h5
Epoch 11/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 698us/step - loss: 1.4524 - accuracy: 0.9093 - val_loss: 0.0846 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 0.07454
Epoch 12/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 641us/step - loss: 1.2381 - accuracy: 0.9231 - val_loss: 0.1014 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00012: val_loss did not improve from 0.07454
Epoch 13/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 675us/step - loss: 1.4516 - accuracy: 0.9093 - val_loss: 0.0931 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00013: val_loss did not improve from 0.07454
Epoch 14/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 644us/step - loss: 1.6197 - accuracy: 0.8984 - val_loss: 0.0947 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 0.07454
Epoch 15/15
364/364 [==============================] - 0s 652us/step - loss: 1.6180 - accuracy: 0.8984 - val_loss: 0.0986 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 0.07454
Epoch 00015: early stopping
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 229us/step
Val Score:  [0.09038299520810446, 1.0]
====================================================================================


plt.title('Accuracy vs Epochs')
plt.plot(model_history[0].history['accuracy'], label='Training Fold 1')
plt.plot(model_history[1].history['accuracy'], label='Training Fold 2')
plt.plot(model_history[2].history['accuracy'], label='Training Fold 3')
plt.plot(model_history[3].history['accuracy'], label='Training Fold 4')
plt.plot(model_history[4].history['accuracy'], label='Training Fold 5')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here, is the accuracy [image: Accuracy image]

And this is an example of training and validation accuracy
[image: train and val image]

This time, I added more dropout layers and regularization to avoid overfitting.

is there any other possibility to change the model to avoid overfitting?

Also, Could I know what is the problem to overcome this?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe try more dropout,, also what is your filter count.. maybe you are just using too many filters, thus ending up with way too many features than needed..

also what are your train & val errors?

Comment: This usually happens when the validation data is not an actual representation of the training data, or maybe imbalanced data with the model giving many false positives. Also include AUC, it gives a better representation.

Comment: How do you get the losses (and accuracies)? I.e. is the standard Keras `fit`, your own code, something else? Show us.

Comment: @murariprasad Now, I added the full code. could, you please tell me what is the problem in this code?

Comment: @dedObed yeah, here is the full code. please check it!

Comment: This is a well known effect of Dropout, not a programming problem!

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy So, do I need to remove these layers to fix the problem?

Comment: There is no problem to start with.

Comment: Dr. Snoopy is right.

Comment: You can try another optimizer and reduce the number of epochs